# Public folder insinde ZF2 module and calling the assets

Tags: module, zend-framework2

I have the following folder structure

```
- Admin (Module)
    - config
    - public
        - css
        - js
        - img
    - src
       - Admin
    - view
        - admin
        - layout
             /admin.phtml
```

How can I use inside the admin.phtml  the css and js files from the upper public directoy.

I know that this

```
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($basePath . '/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

gets it from the root public folder and adding $basePath . 'module/Admin/public/css/bootstrap.min.css' isn't a solution because the module name can change.

Edit: also, the above solution isn't good because my module can be also in the vendor subfolder.

Comment: Check out [AssetManager](https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager) :)

Comment: It doesn't work if i use it in a folder structure like this: \vendor\ensemble\admin\

Comment: Check out the AssetManager - it works. If it doesn't, the configuration is to blame.

Comment: Typically, your public directory does not live inside of your module